# In my state object I need to make an array of my props.initialProps that has been declared in my default props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm aiming to have an array with two different image srcs so when I click a button they change. But After compiling i'm getting Syntax error: C:/Users/kcee4/Documents/GitHub/portfolio/src/body/Projects.js: ***this*** is a reserved word (115:18). Here's my code.

```
class Projects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      card: this.props.initialCards,
      isFirstSrc: true,
      counter: 0,
      imgArray: [{this.props.initialCards.firstImgSrc}, {this.props.initialCards.secondImgSrc}],
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `this` in the constructor as the `props` of the component are automatically passed in (take a look at your function definition).

So, based on that knowledge we can remove all references to `this`:

```
class Projects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      card: props.initialCards,
      isFirstSrc: true,
      counter: 0,
      imgArray: [{props.initialCards.firstImgSrc}, {props.initialCards.secondImgSrc}],
      }
  }
```